# I've tried to plot these subplots but they simply aren't showing up in my output, actually, they are shaded

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
#plotting the independent ordinal variables
plt.figure(1)
plt.subplots(131)
train['Dependents'].value_counts(normalize=True).plot.bar(figsize=(24,6), title='Dependents')
plt.subplots(132)
train['Education'].value_counts(normalize=True).plot.bar(title='Education')
plt.subplots(133)
train['Property_Area'].value_counts(normalize=True).plot.bar(title='Property_Area')
plt.show()
```

here's the image

#[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/V9YgL.png

Comment: That seems like a large amount of subplots.

Comment: Seems your comment has led me to the answer, "subplots" should be "subplot". 
Thanks, I guess